# How to sample from a sequence of numbers but skip a specified number in R?

Tags: r

I would like to sample from 1 to 10 but skip 3 using the sample() function in R. How can I do this?

i.e. sample(1:10 skipping 3, 5, replace=TRUE)

Comment: Instead of `1:10` as the first argument to `sample`, use `c(1:2, 4:10)`.

Comment: or `(1:10)[-3]`

Comment: @Limey: What if I want to exclude 1 from the list?

Answer (score 1):

A few options here, the latter giving it a bit more flexibility if you have more complex cases. The first skips having 3 in the vector to sample from, the latter have it then but then remove it from the values that `sample()` sees:

```
sample(c(1, 2, 4:10), size=5, replace=TRUE)

sample(c(1:10)[-3], size=5,replace=TRUE)

sample_from <- c(1:100)
exclude <- c(3, 6, 72)
sample(sample_from[-exclude], size=5,replace=TRUE)
```

Note that `sample(c(1,2)[-1], size=1)` will return 1's - the `-1` is removing the 1st element of that vector, leaving just one value. The same happened in the other cases - R removed the 3rd element, not elements that were 3. You get `1` and `2` because when `sample()` receives a single value it will sample from 1 to that value, so `sample(2, size=1)` is the same as `sample(1:2, size=1)`. See `?sample` for more.

A hacky-fix for that would be to use `!(... %in% ...)` as "not in"

```
sample(rep(c(1:2), 2)[!c(1:2)%in%c(1)], 500, replace=TRUE)
```

Comment: Why does sample(c(1,2)[-1], 5, replace=TRUE) still includes 1 in its samplings occasionally?

Comment: That creates a vector of length 1, when `sample()` gets a vector of length 1 it will sample the values from 1 to that value - e.g. `sample(5, size=1)` is equivalent to `sample(1:5, size=1)` - see `?sample`

Comment: @JasonChiaKimLeng I've added in some more detail to the answer on that

Comment: Thanks for referencing the documentation. Are you aware of a variation of the sample() function that is able to generate samples of 2,2,2,2,2 from function(c(1:2)[-1],5,replace=TRUE)? ```sample(c(1:2)[!(c(1:2)%in%c(1))], 500, replace=TRUE)``` still generates samples containing 1...

Comment: sorry for missing that! a hacky approach would be to put it into a rep() - see edited code - this creates a vector where each of you elements occurs twice, so even if you only have one element, R gets two